# Redis Cluster: Moving MASTER via Pacemaker/Corosync

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

**My environment:**

I would like to use Redis as a replacement for Memcached.

For my case, I will use 3 servers, each will hold a Redis MASTER. I don't need replication, only sharding. All data will be stored in-memory and I don't care if it gets lost when a server goes down.

```
Server 1: master_1.conf
Server 2: master_2.conf
Server 3: master_3.conf
```

If one server goes down, Pacemaker/Corosync will start the same MASTER on another server (all servers have a shared **read-only** filesystem, so the new MASTER can be started with the same config file, but on another server).

```
Server 1: dead
Server 2: master_1.conf (data wiped), master_2.conf
Server 3: master_3.conf
```

When the faulty server is fixed, the MASTER will return to it. I understand that the data will be wiped during these movements.

```
Server 1: master_1.conf (data wiped)
Server 2: master_2.conf
Server 3: master_3.conf
```

**The question:**

As far I as I understood, what really matters is the NODE ID that gets assigned to a MASTER when a cluster is created. So if I move my MASTER to another server, I need to make sure that it keeps the same NODE ID as on the previous server. Without it, it cannot rejoin a cluster.

However, I couldn't find a configuration option for it. Is there a way to configure the NODE ID in the config file?

I don't care about data loss during movements, I just need to make sure that all 3 MASTERS are running even if they are running on 1 server (if 2 others are down).

```
Server 1: server dead
Server 2: server dead
Server 3: master_1.conf (data wiped), master_2.conf (data wiped), master_3.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can't configure the node id, and don't have to.
Since I have a shared filesystem, I created a separate folder with WRITE capabilities, where all redis servers host their nodes.conf files (nodes_1.conf, nodes_2.conf, nodes_3.conf).

When a redis instance dies on one server, pacemaker starts it on another server with the same configuration and the same nodes.conf file from the shared filesystem.

The instance then automatically rejoins the cluster without any problems.